# How to find hidden / not rendered html in a web page?

Tags: html, web

For example : In the following web page : https://geizhals.de/?cat=umtsover. doing inspect elements i find that some portion of code is not rendered by the browser, but present in html. Is there any way to detect this ?

[image: html source of some part]

I know there can be few heuristics that could be derived for some specific web pages. But is there any generic way to do this ? Assuming I have CSS ( where i could use visibility attributes ) and also if i dont have css info ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They have css attribute `display` set to value `none`.

Comment: Btw these elements are rendered, but just hidden.

Comment: @PetrUnzeitig, Upon hovering through these in inspect elements, it doesn't give me the location of text in the page. That's why i said not rendered. Is there something iam missing ?

Comment: And having css info, there are attributes, like display and visibility, that tell about all this. But I am working on crawled pages that don't have CSS, and was looking for a solution for that.

Comment: Ok I said it wrong, they are not rendered at this point. If you remove or change atrribute `display`, these elements become displayed. But the point is, this is made by CSS, so if your page doesnt working with CSS, you can set element HTML attribute `hidden`, which produced same visual effect. [But it has semantic meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden), so be carefull with it's usage.